# Waiting for a promise natively

Tags: node.js

What I want:

```js
// db.js
const mariadb = require('mariadb');
module.exports = {
 conn: await mariadb.createConnection({ ... }) // mariadb returns a connection with a promise
};
// foo.js
const conn = require('./db').conn;
```

What am I doing:

```js
// db.js
const mariadb = require('mariadb');
module.exports = {
 getConn: mariadb.createConnection({ ... }) // mariadb returns a connection with a promise
};
// foo.js
const getConn = require('./db').getConn;
(async()=>{
    const conn = await getConn;
    // ...
})();
```

I feel it's waste.
Is there any way to wait for a promise until export?

Comment: I am almost certain you don't have to do what you're doing and wait for anything. Simply export `mariadb.createConnection(...)`, then import it as `const db = require('./db.js')`, and finally use it as `db.then(conn => {...})` wherever you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only with [top-level await](https://v8.dev/features/top-level-await), which is not yet supported in Node.

See also [why you may not want to do this](https://gist.github.com/Rich-Harris/0b6f317657f5167663b493c722647221).